# Shadow in NSScrollView in Mac OS X app

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsscrollview

I need two things similar to Pages app in my Mac OS X app. Please view the attached screen shot.

1. I need a shadow on NSScrollView as shown in Mac OS X Pages app.
2. I want my scroll bar to be like the one in Mac OS X Pages app.

[image: UI comparing]

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy way of getting the top shadow is to override the enclosing clip view. This is not ideal however, because it draws the shadow (actually a gradient) behind the controls. I find it good enough.

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

// DFInvertedClipView.h
IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface DFInvertedClipView : NSClipView
@property IBInspectable BOOL shouldDrawTopShadow;
@end

// DFInvertedClipView.m
#import "DFInvertedClipView.h"

@interface DFInvertedClipView ()
@property CGFloat startAlpha;
@end

@implementation DFInvertedClipView

- (BOOL) isFlipped {
    return true;
}

-(void) drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{

    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    if (_shouldDrawTopShadow) {

        NSGradient * gradient = [[NSGradient alloc] initWithStartingColor:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:0.6 alpha:self.startAlpha]
                                                              endingColor:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:0.6 alpha:0.0]];

        NSRect b = [self bounds];
        NSRect topFade = NSMakeRect(NSMinX(b), NSMinY(b), NSWidth(b), 5.0);
        [gradient drawInRect:topFade angle:90];

        NSBezierPath *topLine = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
        [topLine moveToPoint:NSMakePoint(NSMinX(self.bounds), NSMinY(self.bounds))];
        [topLine lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(NSMaxX(self.bounds), NSMinY(self.bounds))];

        CGFloat lineWidth = [[NSScreen mainScreen] backingScaleFactor];
        [topLine setLineWidth:lineWidth];
        [[NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:0.5 alpha:self.startAlpha] setStroke];
        [topLine stroke];
    }


}

-(void) scrollToPoint:(NSPoint)newOrigin
{
    [super scrollToPoint:newOrigin];

    // Grade the shadow darkness based on the displacement from a flush fit
    CGFloat displacementForFullShadow = 40.0; // pixels
    if (newOrigin.y > 0) {
        CGFloat alpha = 1.0/displacementForFullShadow * newOrigin.y; // e.g. linear grade function y = m*x + c (m = 1/displacementForFullShadow, c = 0.0)
        if (alpha > 1.0) {
            alpha = 1.0;
        }
        self.startAlpha = alpha;
    } else {
        self.startAlpha = 0.0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. The shadow of the view above is achieved by setting custom `CALayer` options of this view (you'll be probably interested in `mask`-property). Just check the `View Effects Inspector` from the IB (or you can do it programmatically too - [read this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/))
2. To remove scroll view knobs' light style open NSScrollView attributes inspector in IB and select `Scroller Knobs` style to "Default Style" (second line).

Comment: What options did you set for the layer? Setting a shadow doesn't draw over the other controls.

Comment: @Lupurus use `mask` option. If you define custom `colors` values of this layer you can achieve smooth inner shadow.